# How to completely erase personal data from Mac

Tags: mac, security, privacy

I use browsers Firefox, Chrome and Safari, personal data such as passwords are stored on them. Passwords are stored in Mac Keychain as well.

What is the easiest and reliable way to completely and permanently delete my personal data?

Answer (score 2):

Adding to previous answers & comments...

Which do you want, convenience or security?

Convenience -
just throw out the obvious bits, the ones you can find; let someone else have a rummage through the bits you missed later, at their leisure.

Reasonable Security -
Boot from another drive.
Secure Erase the entire internal HD at the 'most secure' setting & install a fresh OS.

Total security -
Remove the HD & physically destroy it.

The apps etc already on the drive are not licensed for anyone else, neither is the OS - so unless you leave your Apple ID details on there for them [& your car keys & wallet while you're at it], they won't be able to update anything anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you're preparing the Mac for sale, I recommend these steps:

1. Boot off an external drive.
2. Erase your internal hard drive with "zero out data" selected.
3. Do a clean re-install of OS X.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without reinstalling OSX?

Comment: @DUKE For me to answer that well, you'll have to tell me why exactly you don't want to reinstall OS X. Are you just trying to avoid the time/hassle, or is this a case where you're not actually preparing it for sale to a stranger, and you want to leave certain things set up a certain way, because you're setting it up for a friend or relative or something?

Comment: I just want to sell to a stranger, but trying to avoid reinstalling hassle.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sell to a stranger, you can delete all your stuff manually, reset your applications, and write over your free space with the Disk Utility in OX. [Zero out isn't that secure compared to other methods.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201949)

As a middle ground I recommend a [factory reset](http://www.tomsguide.com/faq/id-2330399/restore-macbook-pro-factory-settings.html) and maybe a zero out or whatever you have time for on the free space when you're done just for good measure.

But the arguably most secure method was Spiff's.